# i want to make a screen with list and it should include a drill down concept in android app on gingerbread

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, drilldown

My application should have an activity to show a list of elements. These elements **can be selected** using some checkbox mechanism **AND** if it is clicked **another list on next screen with the sub elements** should be shown.
Need desperate help. 
link to snippet would be preferable. thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two activities extending from ListActivity. Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) to create a listActivity and implement click listener for list items and on click event start second activity...

Comment: for checkboxes, you can create a custom view and inflate each List item row to that view... Alternatively you can use builtin list provided by android... check the id's in android.R.id. used in creating an adapter. check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html